# How to copy the contents only of an Excel cell minus the formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I copy a cell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> and paste it elsewhere in the worksheet, the formatting is also carried along (such as the cell borders, etc). Is there a shortcut to copy only the contents minus any formatting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Paste Special (in the edit menu) to specify exactly what should and should not be pasted.

If you have Excel 2007 or later, pasting normally (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) also works; a dropdown box then appears with options to paste without formatting, etc. You can then click the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to open it and select options.

[image: excel paste example]

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Press F2 on the cell then select the content of the cell and then ctrl+c.

Method 2: Just go to new blank cell and then use the "=FORMULATEXT(A1)". This will convert the cell content to text format. Now copy this new cell.

Comment: But, with Method 2, won't you end up with a new cell that (also) contains `=FORMULATEXT(A1)`? Or, worse yet, `=FORMULATEXT(…)` of some *other* (relatively-addressed) cell (since you didn't say `$A$1`)? But also, Method 2 doesn't seem to work at all if cell `A1` contains a simple value (as opposed to a formula).